# Hive Sql/Python group all connected items together based on a source and destination column

Tags: python, sql, hive

I have a user connection table like this:

| src | dst |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 |

I want the src & dst that are connected appear in the same group, as below:

| src | dst | grp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 7 | 2 |

Is there a way to do this in Hive Sql or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/) package to do that. Here is the sample code

```
import networkx as nx

connections = [
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (4, 5),
    (6, 7)
]

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from(connections)

groups = list(nx.connected_components(G))

node_to_group = {}
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    for node in group:
        node_to_group[node] = i + 1

print("src\t dst\t grp")
for src, dst in connections:
    print(f"{src}\t {dst}\t {node_to_group[src]}")
```

You can check on [my kaggle here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/heinzmdsiahaan/notebook8d3c9ebc76)